# maven java compilation: is there concurrent mode?

Tags: java, maven

Is there a possibility to compile in a maven project 2 modules concurrently, if they don't have mutual dependency? (Java)

Example: I have a pom.xml (project) which has 3 modules - A, B and C.

C is dependent on B.
B and A are not dependent on anything.

So, when drawing the dependency DAG, it seems that we have 2 roots: A and B.
Can we run maven in such a concurrent way, that A and B will start concurrently, and C will be started after compilation of B?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. Sorry for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven 3.x has the capability to perform parallel builds. The command is as follows:

> mvn -T 2 clean install # Builds with 2 threads
>   mvn -T 4C clean install# 4 thread per cpu core
>   mvn -T 2.5C clean install # 2.5 thread per cpu core

You can find out more [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3).